# React.createRef always null

Tags: reactjs

I am probably doing something really stupid here, but for the life of me, I cannot figure out why `ref` is always null.

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react';

class MyComponent extends PureComponent {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.myRef = React.createRef();
    console.log(this.myRef);
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log(this.myRef);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    console.log('unmounting');
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.myRef);
    return (
      <div ref={this.myRef}>
        foobar
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Console:

```
{current: null}
{current: null}
{current: null}
```

I am on React 16.3. What am I missing?

Comment: Works for me. Nothing seems wrong with your code.

Comment: It's working. https://codesandbox.io/s/40z5o73wz0

Comment: Works for me too. Check this link to understand more about refs https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html

Comment: There must be some side effect from my other code. It works standalone as you pointed out. But I use that code in one of my project's components, I see `{current: null}`. So bizarre.

Comment: @deruse `this` issue? You can put more codes for us to check out.

Comment: Share your other component code from wr MyComponent gets called to understand better

Comment: CAn you try doing console log of this.myRef in render before return instead of componentDidMount and check. This should print current node when it is getting called from other component. Perhaps MyComponent is unmounted by the time its getting called and that’s why you see null

Comment: Still `{current: null}`. The other code is just a App.jsx which calls this component for a specific route. I have simplified it to just render on the client (no server side rendering), but that didn't help...

Comment: Does not look like the component is unmounting.

Comment: omg, I was on react 16.3 but react-dom 16.2. bumping react-dom to 16.3 fixed the issue.

Comment: Great. Put that as an answer so that others will be benefitted

Comment: I was adding `ref={this.myRef}` in a component that time it was showing `{current: null}` because that component data not loaded at same time. So, I used `setTimeout` in `componentDidMount` then it was working. So, next time I used myRef in exact component and it was working.  my need was to find that component element height. So, I used `const height = this.myRef.current.clientHeight;` in `componentDidMount`.

Answer (score 12):

omg, I was on react 16.3 but react-dom 16.2. bumping react-dom to 16.3 fixed the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I used this.myRef.value that retured me null. Now I use this.myRef.**current** that works!

Answer (score 0):

It could also be due to your element not mounting at `componentDidMount()`

Instead try printing the value inside of a `componentDidUpdate()`